# Where is "Hefsek" defined first?

Tags: blessing, hefsek-interruption, hamotzi-beracha

I am looking for the initial mention of the word "Hefsek" where it refers to a gap or interruption between saying a blessing and carrying it out. Shulchan Aruch, Orech Chaim, 167:6 discusses how certain statements do not create a Hefsek after the blessing, and I am looking for the earliest definition of what a Hefsek is.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Dave and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: גמרא ברכות כדי לגמור את כולו

Comment: ברכות דף כג,א גמרא  מר סבר אם שהה כדי לגמור את כולה חוזר לראש ומר סבר למקום שפסק אמר רב אשי האי אם שהה אם לא שהה מיבעי ליה אלא דכולי עלמא אם שהה כדי לגמור את כולה חוזר לראש